# How to insert a number to each array in an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

From:
arr1 = np.array([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ])

To:
arr1 = np.array([ [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 4, 5, 6], [0, 7, 8, 9] ])

Comment: `arr1` is not an array of arrays.  It is one array with shape (3,3), a 2d array.  You apparently want concatenate it with a `np.zeros((3,1), int)` array.  Have you read about `np.concatenate`?

Comment: i just tried a few concatenation commands but it doesn't seem to fix my problem, i actually want to insert 1's at the 0th position to each vector within that array, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this with [`numpy.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html):

```
x = 0
new = np.full((arr1.shape[0], arr1.shape[1] + 1), x)
new[:, 1:] = arr1
```

**Output**

```
new
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 7, 8, 9]])
```

---

Note that you can assign any value to `x`.

Comment: @AhmadJomaa Nice!! Please consider voting and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Your (3,3) 2d array:

```
In [100]: arr1 = np.array([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ])
In [101]: arr1
Out[101]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

A new (3,4) array:

```
In [102]: np.concatenate((np.zeros((3,1),int),arr1), axis=1)
Out[102]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Any other `(3,1)` array (or even a (3,n)) could be added "at the start" like this.